# Почему не все ресурсы из android.R доступны?

Tags: android, resources

В приложении предполагается локализация, поэтому хочется поменьше засорять проект, пользуясь встроенными ресурсами андроид. Пытаюсь использовать в приложении строку, которая хранится в android.R.string.noApplications, но студия пишет "cannot resolve symbol noApplications" и приложение не собирается. Почему так? Ведь я могу использовать другие строки из этого файла, и на конкретно этой нет никаких спецификаторов доступа. Можно ли и где взять системные строки с локализацией?

Answer (score 1):

Набор доступных системных строковых ресурсов [весьма ограничен](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html)

Я не совсем уверен, но видимо связано это с тем, что класс R системных ресурсов не автогенерируется, а создан статическим и секция string содержит следующие публичные ключи:

```
public static final class string {
    public static final int VideoView_error_button = 17039376;
    public static final int VideoView_error_text_invalid_progressive_playback = 17039381;
    public static final int VideoView_error_text_unknown = 17039377;
    public static final int VideoView_error_title = 17039378;
    public static final int cancel = 17039360;
    public static final int copy = 17039361;
    public static final int copyUrl = 17039362;
    public static final int cut = 17039363;
    public static final int defaultMsisdnAlphaTag = 17039365;
    public static final int defaultVoiceMailAlphaTag = 17039364;
    public static final int dialog_alert_title = 17039380;
    public static final int emptyPhoneNumber = 17039366;
    public static final int fingerprint_icon_content_description = 17039384;
    public static final int httpErrorBadUrl = 17039367;
    public static final int httpErrorUnsupportedScheme = 17039368;
    public static final int no = 17039369;
    public static final int ok = 17039370;
    public static final int paste = 17039371;
    public static final int search_go = 17039372;
    public static final int selectAll = 17039373;
    public static final int selectTextMode = 17039382;
    public static final int status_bar_notification_info_overflow = 17039383;
    public static final int unknownName = 17039374;
    public static final int untitled = 17039375;
    public static final int yes = 17039379;

    public string() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
}
```

соответственно, получить доступ к прочим ключам "извне" нет возможности.

В частности, скриншот декомпиляции android.jar и R.class в нем:

[image: screen]